# Regarding Tezos Fees estimation

Tags: fees, gas

Just wanted to understand where these constants are coming from ? https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/master/packages/taquito/src/constants.ts#L1
Also recently the gas limit has been limit to 1000. However, the naive estimator provides more that that. can you please explain ? Also because constants for gas limit are used in the fee estimation so isn't it the fees calculation is estimating higher fees because the gas limit constants have higher value as compared to 1000 ?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to TSE! if you have multiple questions regarding fees i would invite you to split them so that the answers can stay focused on one issue at a time thanks!